# How to get ALL communities from DSpace rest api

Tags: rest, api, dspace

Using the endpoint:

```
GET https://mydspace.org/rest/communities/
```

I seem to only get `100` results returned. I can't see any options in the documentation to return more.
 How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Most of the DSpace rest endpoints support a limit parameter.  I suppose that there is some maximum size that you can request, but the limit should be able to go higher than 100.

   - https://demo.dspace.org/rest/communities?limit=500
2. If you still are unable to retrieve everything in one request (or if you timeout), you can paginate through the results in your code.

   - https://demo.dspace.org/rest/communities?limit=100
   - https://demo.dspace.org/rest/communities?offset=100&limit=100
   - https://demo.dspace.org/rest/communities?offset=200&limit=100
3. There is an endpoint (in DSpace 6) that will allow you to retrieve the ids and handles for the full hierarchy.

   - https://demo.dspace.org/rest/hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

It's not very prominent, but pagination of REST responses is documented at https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/REST+API#RESTAPI-RESTEndpoints just above "Index / Authentication".